# What do I do my aloe plant has root rot

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, roots, aloe, rot

Hi I was wondering if someone could help me. I discovered root rot on my plant. I removed the rotten leafs. But I want to know if I can keep the roots.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Better remove rotten roots. Those roots contain fungus and bacteria that causes root rot. Then use a proper potting mix and replant the aloe. Use more perlite to absorb excess moisture.

Always check the surface soil dryness before watering, [How To Water Plants | All Thing About Watering](https://gardenplantslife.com/how-to-water-plants/).